# Using Bootstrap to make a grid element automatically fill the parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to achieve a dynamic layout option for a site, but I can't nail down how to make this work. The effect I'm trying to create should look like this:

[image: example.jpg]

Where:

"1" will have text, and have a dynamic height;

"2" will have a background color and also fill the containing div below it, with a small vector image centered horizontally and vertically. I want to use a dynamic height on this so no matter how much text is in "1", it fills the rest of the bottom of this container;

"3" is an image (img-responsive) that fills the right half of the container. It will be what sets the height of the container div, with the possibility of different sized images being implemented.

I want these to display as shown on desktop browsers and landscape tablets, but to fall into a single column when its viewed on a smaller screen format.

I'm currently using two col-md-6 for each of these, and had the desired background color on the container. The problem I'm running into with bootstrap is when the screen is between 992px and 1200px, the content is collapsing to a smaller screen size, but it is making the bottom of "2" extend beyond the bottom of "3".

I've tried using flexbox for this, but when I use it in conjunction with col-md-6, it doesn't collapse to the single column on the smaller screen sizes. It also just doesn't seem to work too nicely with bootstrap 3.

I'm open to any type of solution outside of completely taking out bootstrap. Thank you all so much for your time and assistance!

**EDIT 1:**

Totally forgot to add the code. What I have so far is as follows:

https://jsfiddle.net/b86k1myr/

```
<div>
```

It's kind of wonky because bootstrap isnt also enabled. But that's what I have for that so far. The other attempt with flexbox is as follows:

https://jsfiddle.net/mkg73uvk/

Comment: nice picture, however we need your code.

Comment: yeah im a bonehead and totally forgot to add that. I'm adding it now! My apologies

Comment: i reversed my vote, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As a tip for the future, you should always post the markup you're using currently.

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried to put the code in on here in the edit, but it wasn't playing nice with me and wouldnt display all of it. So I opted to put it in jsfiddle.

As for this answer, it's pretty much how I have it set up, but it doesnt solve the issue im having with in the set screen ranges I described above. whats happening is when the screen size is between 1200px and about 990px, the "2" area goes beyond the bottom of "3", and adds the background below it.

Comment: You have a lot of extra stuff going on there. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/ewntyhry/ (specifically, there was a `height: 300px` on the glyphicon that was causing your main issue, and you weren't using `row`s correctly.. or at all.)

Comment: I got to try this today, and it didn't actually fix the problem of "2" filling the rest of the container div (as the "3" image is taller than the text box significantly). It still remains smaller and doesn't fill the remainder of what would be the column on the left, its height remains too small. is there a way to do this dynamically?